# How to display a file extension field to a Sharepoint 2010 document library

Tags: 2007, web-part, document-library

I'm trying to make file extensions show in a Document library webpart in SharePoint 2007.

I don't have SharePoint designer, and have only run across ways to do this in SP 2010 or later versions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by getting SharePoint Designer. It's a FREE powerful tool, and a must have if you want to tackle something like this.

This is an article that does exactly what you want:
http://www.itwriting.com/blog/articles/how-to-show-file-extensions-in-sharepoint-2007-document-lists

Basic Steps:

- Select the webpart you want to add the File Extension to
- Add Column
- RightClick column --> Add Formula
- Type: **@File_x0020_Type**
- Save & Publish the modified view

Comment: Thanks, but I work at a large corporation that doesn't let me publish from Designer.  I'm limited to editing SP pages via the IE GUI.